# What is the area bounded by the curve $r^2 + \theta^2 = 1$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, area, curves

What is the area bounded by the curve $r^2 + \theta^2 = 1$? (given in polar coordinates)

My approach was to calculate the definite integral:
$$\frac12 \int_0^1 (1-\theta^2) \, d\theta$$

Integration limits are $0$ to $1$ because this is the domain of $r$.
The final answer I got is $\frac13$ while the answer in the book is $\frac23$.

Shouldn't I multiply the integral by $\frac12$ as written above? Is there something else wrong in my way?

Comment: No. Zoltan has applied the good formula.

Comment: @JeanMarie, didn't recognize he used the standard formula $\frac{1}{2} \int r^2 d\theta.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the range of $\theta$ is not $[0,1]$ but $[-1,1].$

Answer (score 2):

There is a symmetry you are failing to exploit. If $(r,\theta)$ is on the graph so is $(-r,-\theta)$ so that your formula only counts half the area.